# How copy file in Ruby (custom Puppet type)?

Tags: ruby, puppet

I am creating a custom puppet type. I am quiet new to Ruby, so I have a little problem. I have two params, `dest` and `file`:

```
newparam(:dest) do
    desc "The destination of the file"
    isnamevar

    validate do |value|
      unless Puppet::Util.absolute_path?(value)
        fail Puppet::Error, "File paths must be fully qualified, not '#{value}'"
      end
    end
  end

newparam(:file) do
    desc "The file to be copied."

   FileUtils.cp(file, dest)
   # As source I would like to use the value passed by :file.
   # As destination I would like to use the value passed by :dest above
end
```

As source I would like to use the value passed by `:file`.
As destination I would like to use the value passed by `:dest`. 
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to take a step back and think about what your type is supposed to model.

Are you trying to recreate the `file` type's `source` property? (Do you really need to?)

Your `dest` should likely be a property, and the copying will happen during its `sync` action. But this model will be rather clunky abstraction. You should create a new question, describe what your type needs to do and ask for advice on how to approach your greater problem.